# What would be the best way to create a music answer tone for cellular phones?

Tags: mobile, voip, ringtone

Can someone give me the logistics of it? Or would it be as easy as downloading software like creating a ringtone? I know carriers can do it, but is it possible?

Comment: You mean how to make a ringtone converter or how to find one to use? The latter belongs on Superuser I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of downloadable pieces of software for all major phone manufacturers that allow you to create ringtones for your phone.  Find the correct one for your phone and follow the instructions.  Usually the cost is free or very minimal.

Comment: I'm sorry I actually meant an answer tone not ringtone. Ringtones are easy but I haven't figured out the answer tone

Comment: I don't understand the difference or are you talking about the single or double tone you get when you phone someone?  I think you probably need to control the network to change that!